# Update two tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables, Dtable d and Rtable r. I want to update both tables with one query (important!) in the following order: first setting all Dtable matching row values with a value from Rtable. Then - changing the value from Rtable. In Rtable there will always be a record that matches a key, but in Dtable there can be 0,1 or many records that matches the key. I came up with the following select:

```
UPDATE Dtable d, Rtable r

SET
    d.value = r.value,
    r.value = 0
WHERE
    d.key = 403 AND d.value = 0 AND r.id = 403
```

But the problem here is that if I have multiple records in Dtable that match the key, only first one gets updated with value from Rtable, then the value of Rtable changes, and second row from Dtable already gets updated with changed value from Rtable, which is not what I want.

Here's an example of contents of both tables before update:

```
Dtable             Rtable
---------------    --------------- 
| key | value |    | key | value |
---------------    ---------------
| 403 |   0   |    | 403 |   105 |
---------------    ---------------
| 403 |   0   |
---------------
```

And this is what i want it to look after the update:

```
Dtable             Rtable
---------------    --------------- 
| key | value |    | key | value |
---------------    ---------------
| 403 |  105  |    | 403 |   0   |
---------------    ---------------
| 403 |  105  |
---------------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results -- this would enhance your description.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?????  It's not possible.

Comment: 100% sure it is not possible?

Comment: I finally tested this out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc5b4/1). As I suspected; your original query actually works (assuming `r.id` is actually a typo just here; otherwise the query would not have run at all). Did you ever actually try it, or did you just assume the value assigned to r.value would be used for the changes the update applies to later rows' d.value?

Comment: tried it, of course, and in Dtable it updated only first record, second remained zero.

Comment: Interestingly enough, your fiddle example really works, while my real life tables don't. Maybe some indexes or additional fields make it work differently which makes me think there is no certain way to guarantee this will work the way i want in absolutely all situations. Thanks for trying, appreciate that!

Comment: @Maris maybe adding the full create statements for both tables, and the **exact** update query you are using, to the question could help track down the issue

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you closer:

```
UPDATE Dtable s, Rtable r
SET s.value = r.value,
r.value = 0
FROM Rtable r
JOIN Dtable d
ON r.key = d.key
WHERE d.key = 403;
```

Comment: this doesn't have the right syntax! Plus, joining.. again how will it work if there is no values in Dtable, it still should update Rtable

Comment: There is no full outer join in MySQL; no single query can be guaranteed to update both tables if either could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
UPDATE Dtable d
INNER JOIN Rtable r
ON d.key = r.key
SET
d.value = r.value,
r.value = 0
WHERE
d.key = 403 AND d.value = 0 AND r.id = 403
```

Comment: INNER JOIN? That will not update Rtable if there is no at least one matching record from Dtable!

Comment: Assuming `key` and `id` are the same field; neither will the original. `d.key = 403 AND r.id = 403` make it effectively the same query; though much more cryptic from the use of "comma join" syntax that has been out of favor for decades.